# Django 1.7 migrations using parent class

Tags: python, django, migration

I'm writing a migration using django 1.7, I read some articles about it, but i'm not understand how can use a hierarchy like in de models, country__name = 'MEXICO' and returned a MX key, with this value i can insert into the table i guessing it is my  problem.

```
def add_holder_data(apps, schema_editor):
    table = 'PODER.DBF'
    m = MigrationFromDBase()
    fields = json.dumps(m.fetch_dbase_table(table))

    Holder = apps.get_model('holder', 'Holder')
    data = []
    for f in json.loads(fields):
        if int(f['NREFPOD']) > 0 and int(f['NREFPOD']) != None:
        data.append(
            Holder(
                id=int(f['NREFPOD']), name =f['SOLICITA'],  street = f['CALLE'], city = f['CIUDAD'],
                   cp = f['CODIGO'], country__name = f['PAIS'], nationality = f['NACION'], rfc = f['RFC'],
                   power = f['PODER_EN'], no_rgp = f['NORGP'], person_type = f['PERFISICA'],
                   national = f['NACIONAL'], compulsa = int(f['COMPULSA'])
            )
        )
    Holder.objects.bulk_create(data)


def remove_holder_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Holder = apps.get_model('holder', 'Holder')
    Holder.objects.all().delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [('holder','0001_initial')]

    operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(
        add_holder_data,
        reverse_code=remove_holder_data
        ),
    ]
```

if i use country = f['PAIS'] it give me an error: value too long for type character varying(2), it's because f['PAIS] has a fullname. and the class has four characters in country.code field.

if i use country__name = f['PAIS'] it give me an error: TypeError: 'country_name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function, in this case i'don't know why the error.

I need get first the country codes?.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name=_('Código'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name=_('Nombre'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the Holder definition:

```
class Holder(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, verbose_name=_('Nombre')) 
    street = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True,     verbose_name=_('Calle'))
    city = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Ciudad'))
    cp = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Código Postal'))
    country = models.CharField(Country, max_length=50)
    nationality = models.CharField(Nacionality, blank=True, max_length=50)
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, verbose_name=_('RFC'))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Can you paste definition of Holder? Does `Holder(..., country=Country(code=..., name=f['PAIS'])), ...)` work?

Answer (score 0):

Well the way to solve the problem was, clean the data from country, and change my model of Holder

```
class Holder(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Nombre')) 
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,     verbose_name=_('Calle'))
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Ciudad'))
     cp = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Código Postal'))
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    nationality = models.CharField(Nacionality, blank=True, max_length=50)
    rfc = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True, verbose_name=_('RFC'))
```

after it always got an error like:  Must be an object of class Country, and discover when i was printing the object it send me `__fake__.Holder object` using `apps.get_model('app', 'class')` but if imported the class as `from holder import Holder`it printed `holder.Holder object`, so i think both will be the same type of objects to retrive a correct Country Model object and this is my migration class.

```
from addons.utility import MigrationFromDBase
import simplejson as json

from addons.tools import CapitalizeMultiplesWords, CleanEmptySpaceInWords,  CleanUnicode, UniqueJson

def discover_country(instance, country):
    """
     Cleaned the string to get the country city
     :param country: is a country from dbase and it contains no normalized data
     :return: Country Object
    """
    obj = instance
    if country.find('_n_') != -1:
        _clean_country =   CleanEmptySpaceInWords(str(CapitalizeMultiplesWords(country)))
    else:
        _clean_country =  CleanUnicode(str(CleanEmptySpaceInWords(str(CapitalizeMultiplesWords(country)))))
    try:
        _country = obj.objects.get(name = _clean_country)
    except obj.DoesNotExist:
        _country = obj.objects.get(name = 'unknown')
    return _country



def add_holder_data(apps, schema_editor):
    table = 'TABLE.DBF'
    m = MigrationFromDBase()
    fields = json.dumps(m.fetch_dbase_table(table))

    holder_instance = apps.get_model('holder', 'Holder')
    country_instance = apps.get_model('addons', 'Country')


    for f in UniqueJson(json.loads(fields), 'NREFPOD'):
        if int(f['NREFPOD']) > 0 and int(f['NREFPOD']) != None:

            if f['SOLICITA'].strip() == "" :
                f['SOLICITA'] = 'unknown'
            if f['PERFISICA'].strip() == "":
                f['PERFISICA'] = ''
            if f['NACIONAL'].strip() == "":
                f['NACIONAL'] = ''
            _country = discover_country(country_instance, f['PAIS'])
            holder_instance.objects.get_or_create (
                id=int(f['NREFPOD']), name = f['SOLICITA'],  street = f['CALLE'], city = f['CIUDAD'],
                   cp = f['CODIGO'], country = _country, rfc = f['RFC'],
                   power = f['PODER_EN'], no_rgp = f['NORGP'], person_type = f['PERFISICA'],
                   national = f['NACIONAL'], compulsa = int(f['COMPULSA'])
            )


def remove_holder_data(apps, schema_editor):
    Holder = apps.get_model('holder', 'Holder')
    Holder.objects.all().delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [('holder','0001_initial')]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
        add_holder_data,
        reverse_code=remove_holder_data
        ),
    ]
```